# Communication between fragments in landscape mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have two fragments in my app, FragmetHome and FragmentDetails. FragmentHome has a recycler view so when I click on an item FragmentDetails appears. This works fine for portrait mode. In landscape mode I want to achieve that FragmentHome and FragmentDetails appear on screen at the same time. I've made XML file for landscape mode with two FragmentContainerViews. The problem is, when I click on the game, instead of opening to the right(in FragmentDetails) it opens in FragmentHome again so I end up with two FragmentDetails showing on the screen. What should I do so that FragmentDetails opens next to FragmentHome?

I've tried making two navGraphs but got conflicting id's error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.